# How can I get this slide out nav menu working with react-router and framer-motion?

Tags: react-router-dom, framer-motion

The animation when tapping the hamburger menu is working perfectly (though the css positioning is off, and needs to be fixed). But when the user taps one of the links in the nav (whether it is a new page or the page they are on), I want the animation in reverse (with either the current page or the new page, depending upon which link they press)

[Code in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-exploration-3-jrvb9)

Any ideas on the one, or probably many things I am doing wrong?

Comment: Let me see if I understand it. It already works as you want with the only exception being that when they click a link, the overlay with hamburger menu does not slide back in place but rather just jerks back. All you want is for it to slide from right to left gracefully, is that right? Besides that, it works as it should?

Comment: Exactly, and I think that may be due to the useEffect that sets the state to closed, but without it, it is even worse.